# Buffer overflow with pointer issue

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit

I am trying to figure out this buffer overflow exploit. Any pointer would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct node_t {
        int x;
        char y;
        float z;
} node_p;

void unsafe() {
  int read_char;
  int other_value = 0xFFFF;
  int* protector = (int *)malloc(sizeof(node_p)*33);
  char buffer[24];
  printf("Input string):\n");
  read(0, buffer, 1000);
  read_char = strlen(buffer);
  if (*(&protector + other_value) == 0xbadf00d) {
          if (read_char > 24) {
                  printf("\n\too many char!\n");
                  exit(-1);
        } else {
          printf("exploit accessed");
        }
  }
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  unsafe();
  return 0;

}
```

After adding other value to protector I think I get the address of protector to overflow as 0xBA5F015
How to approach this

Comment: try compile with gcc delme.c -Wall -Werror and fix errors

Comment: The goal is not to fix the error, but to access the exploit. :) I was wondering what is the good way of doing it. 
I am sorry, I am still learning C

Comment: You *must* fix the error: *'characters_read': undeclared identifier*. It's always best to copy/paste the actual code that compiled.

Comment: I am sorry, fixed. I was playing with some variables and forgot to align them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine code below to see if it helps. Main point is that `badf00d` is the trigger in existing code (the exploit) and the malicious program is loaded via the `read` call.

Usually, the goal is to discover the correct value for `other_value` and to fuzz the input to discover the vulnerability in `read`.

The read input is where the exploit inserts malicioius code.  1000 bytes is too much for the local heap allocated by `buffer` which has only 24 bytes.

Notice that adding `0xffff` to `protector` puts the address way way far away from `after_buffer` that is where the exploit trigger exist and the exploit wants to execute. The exploit is hoping at trigger address there is some specific value `badf00d`.

A couple of possible outcomes from here:
Knowing that value exist confirms that when the function returns the malicious code will have taking control of the program counter.

Knowing that value exist confirms that some trigger can be invoked to load the malicious code.

Once execution is redirected by the `badf00d` any code on the stack can execute.

```
   read_char=0x0c999c
 other_value=0x0c9998
   protector=0x0c9990
      buffer=0x0c99a0
after_buffer=0x0c998f

protector+offset=0x149988
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct node_t {
        int x;
        char y;
        float z;
} node_p;

void unsafe() {
  int read_char;
  int other_value = 0xFFFF;
  int* protector = (int *)malloc(sizeof(node_p)*33);
  char buffer[24];
  char after_buffer;

  printf("   read_char=%p\n", &read_char);
  printf(" other_value=%p\n", &other_value);
  printf("   protector=%p\n", &protector);
  printf("      buffer=%p\n", &buffer);
  printf("after_buffer=%p\n", &after_buffer);
  printf("\n");
  printf("protector+offset=%p\n", (&protector + other_value) );
  return;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  unsafe();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I never cared about hacks and intrusion code... but ... I don't get it. How is the heap pointer of any help here? Could it not as well just be a char? You want to overwrite the stack, not?

Comment: @BitTickler, that is how I understand it, overwriting the stack and executing code of your choosing is the goal of these lessons, the code looks somewhat educational